# HTTP call is never made flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

### EDIT

Moving the code fixed the issue but im getting this error now.
[image: Error]

I am trying to debug an issue and my http call is never hit. I had to redesign the wiget to make it stateful so I think I missed something. Ive never done a http call on a screen load we normally do them in button click.

Here is the code:

```
class FlutterReduxApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final User user;

 const FlutterReduxApp({Key key, @required this.user}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _FlutterReduxAppState(user);
}


class _FlutterReduxAppState extends State<FlutterReduxApp> {
final User user;

 final store = Store<CategoryState>(stateReducer,
     initialState: CategoryState([

    if(features.isCheckInOn) HomeCategory(0, Icons.check, Colors.blue[800], "Check In", [Task(0, "Check In", true),]),
    HomeCategory(1, Icons.chat_bubble, Colors.red, "Forums", [ Task(1, "Questions", true),]),
    HomeCategory(2, Icons.star, Colors.blue[200], "Goals", [ Task(2, "Goals", true),]),
    HomeCategory(3, Icons.monetization_on, Colors.orange[700], "Budget", [ Task(3, "Budget", true),]),
    HomeCategory(4, Icons.shopping_basket, Colors.brown[300], "Shopping", [ Task(4, "Items", true),]),
    HomeCategory(5, Icons.calendar_today, Colors.purple[900], "My Day & Calendar", [ Task(4, "Events", false),]),
    HomeCategory(6, Icons.check_circle_outline, Colors.teal[700], "Check Out", [ Task(4, "Tasks", false),]),
    HomeCategory(7, Icons.dock, Colors.grey[700], "Connect", [ Task(4, "Tasks", false),]),
    HomeCategory(8, Icons.local_pharmacy, Colors.green, "My Medication", [ Task(4, "Tasks", false),]),
    HomeCategory(9, Icons.settings, Colors.yellow[800], "Settings", [ Task(4, "Tasks", false),]),
  ]),

  );

   _FlutterReduxAppState(this.user);


 static Features features;
  @override
  void initState () {
   super.initState();
   features = getFeatureStatus(user.userId) as Features;


}
```

### HTTP CALL

```
  Future<Features> getFeatureStatus(String userID) async {

   Features _features;

   final response =
  await http.post('http://url/api/FeaturesGet',
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", 
             'Accept': 'application/json',},
  body: json.encode({'userID' : userID }));

// If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON 

      _features = Features.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));



      return _features;



 }
```

No breakpoints are getting hit at all

Comment: There is not HTTP call in your code.

Comment: its the  features = getFeatureStatus(user.userId) as Features; I'll edit it and add it. I cant even get a breakpoint to get hit anywhere

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your post call. You've double checked that your API is working as intended? Since it's your own API, only you can test it.

Comment: How is features.initState() being called?

Comment: Yeah i think i found the issue : this gets called before the features object is created.   if(features.isCheckInOn) HomeCategory(0, Icons.check, Colors.blue[800], "Check In", [Task(0, "Check In", true),]),

Comment: but does moving that change anything? init state isnt called.

Comment: Moving the code fixed the issue and the call is working but I am getting an error. I'm attaching the error screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

`getFeatureStatus` returns a `Future<Features>` not a `Feature`, so your assignment (`features = getFeatureStatus(user.userId) as Features`) is of the wrong type. You need to either `await` the `Future<Features>` returned by `getFeatureStatus` or use `Future.then` to register a callback that sets `features` when the future completes.

Also, you're referencing `features` in the initializer for `store` which is probably going to cause issues since it most likely will be `null` when you create an instance of `_FlutterReduxAppState`. This will result in you getting a `NullPointerException` at `if(features.isCheckInOn)` in your code.